# How to convert ISO 8601 timestamp without timezone to ISO 8601 timestamp with timezone in PHP?

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp, iso8601, gmt

My timestamp is like this:

```
$timestamp = "2018-08-28T08:49:44+00:00";
```

Easy to convert this to a unix timestamp:

```
$unixtime = strtotime($timestamp);
echo $unixtime; // result: 1535446184
```

My desired result is to get the timestamp with timezone for my current timezone. It should be like this:

```
$timestamp_with_timezone = "2018-08-28T10:49:44+02:00";
```

However if I do:

```
echo date('c',$unixtime);
```

The result is again:

```
2018-08-28T08:49:44+00:00
```

What is the correct way to get the desired local time date in ISO 8601 format?

Comment: Yes, but what do you "really" want? ;-)  The time with the time-zone of where the server is located, or the time-zone where the user is located?  The first would require you to know the time-zone settings of the server which is running your PHP website, and the second would require the user to send information about the user's location (or perhaps they have a user-preferences table in the database where they store their preferred time-zone???).

Comment: True I should have clarified this even more. However this is for modifiying the publish date of news articles therefore I need the timezone of the country where the website is hosted: In WordPress I can get it with `get_option('timezone_string')`

Comment: If I need the server time I could use `date_default_timezone_get()` and if I need the users time it entirely depends on from where I get it, just for the interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
// DateTime automatically parses this format, no need for DateTime::createFromFormat()
$date = new DateTime("2018-08-28T08:49:44+00:00");

// Set the timezone (mine here)
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));

// Output: 2018-08-28T10:49:44+02:00
echo $date->format('c');
```

---

- [`DateTime::setTimezone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)
- [`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)
- [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: @Blackbam thanks for the edit ! I first wrote this on a single line, forgot to remove the echo when pasting and splitting my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the TimeZone of the DateTime object:

```
$timestamp = "2018-08-28T08:49:44+00:00";

$date = date_create($timestamp);

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Amsterdam'));

echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```